# Loop from active cell to first empty cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have recorded, and adjusted a code that selects a cell (F2) then enters the information that is already in that cell.

```
Sub testing()
'
' testing Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+T
'
    ActiveCell.Select
    Application.SendKeys "{F2}"
    Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

I need to do this is because I have a summary with formulas that look up the information within the data using index match and I paste this from an export from our accounts system. Without completing this task for what can be tens of thousands of cells the formula doesn't recognise the number.

I am trying to get this to loop from whatever cell is selected when I activate the macro and end when it reaches an empty cell. It is not going to start from the same cell each time as I want this to work on different sheets each time.

I found code that starts from a specific cell each time and then stops but when I adjust it to start from the active cell it crashes. Alternative code doesn't stop at the bottom the data and goes till Excel crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub refresher()
    While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
        Application.SendKeys "{F2}"
        Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
        DoEvents
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Wend
End Sub
```

It will march down a column, refreshing each cell, until a blank is found.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the activecell row and use a .end function to support such that:

```
   dim ac as long, col as long, ec as long, i as long
   ac = activecell.row
   col = activecell.column
   ec = cells(ac,col).end(xldown).row
   for i = ac to ec
       'do something with cells(i,col)
   next i
```